# Maven dependencies incompatibility when using spring cloud and spring boot 2.0.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

my code is as below when I try to start the application. I see a lot of spring exceptions which seeks like dependencies issues.I used spring initializer to generate the application and using springboot 2.0.1. Please help in getting the appropriate configuration to work with pivotal cloud foundy service registry and discovery, this is happening when I try to use circuit breaker as well

consolelog is as follows:

```
2018-04-29 12:05:00.512  INFO 17300 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@17497425: startup date [Sun Apr 29 12:05:00 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-29 12:05:00.970  INFO 17300 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-04-29 12:05:01.017  INFO 17300 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa3e011e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2018-04-29 12:05:01.625  INFO 17300 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
2018-04-29 12:05:02.767  WARN 17300 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/message-generation/default": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2018-04-29 12:05:02.778  INFO 17300 --- [           main] c.p.H.R.RestServiceProducerApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-04-29 12:05:02.800  INFO 17300 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3f390d63: startup date [Sun Apr 29 12:05:02 CDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@17497425
2018-04-29 12:05:03.463 ERROR 17300 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.authenticationEventPublisher
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.poc.HystrixCircuitBreaker.RestServiceProducer.RestServiceProducerApplication.main(RestServiceProducerApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6d06d69c]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:665) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:633) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1012) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:164) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:153) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:203) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:115) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:265) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:254) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:196) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:116) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.access.WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 38 common frames omitted

2018-04-29 12:05:03.464  INFO 17300 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3f390d63: startup date [Sun Apr 29 12:05:02 CDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@17497425
2018-04-29 12:05:03.466  WARN 17300 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6d06d69c]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:665) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:633) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:390) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:889) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:875) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:810) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.poc.HystrixCircuitBreaker.RestServiceProducer.RestServiceProducerApplication.main(RestServiceProducerApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.access.WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 24 common frames omitted



//pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.poc.HystrixCircuitBreaker</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestServiceProducer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>RestServiceProducer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-services.version>2.0.0.M1</spring-cloud-services.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-services.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>

//Config class
package com.poc.HystrixCircuitBreaker.RestServiceProducer;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class RestServiceProducerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestServiceProducerApplication.class, args);
    }
}

//applicatoin.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: message-generation

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false




  Please help me in this regards, I wanted to deploy this app into PCF
```

Comment: The short answer is that you probably want to use Spring Boot 1.5 & SCS 1.5, especially if you want something that just works.  To get Spring Boot 2.0 support, you need Spring Cloud Finchley & SCS 2.0.  At the time of writing, Finchley is still only RC and SCS just had a first milestone.  You can use these, but they're not GA so you get what you get.  My suggestion, would be at least to try your demo app with SB 1.5 & SCS 1.5 to see if it works.  That would give you a sanity check that you're configuring things correctly and help to rule out problems with pre-release code. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Finchley.M9 supports `Spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE`

But I tried it on my local for `Spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE` and it's working fine.

Try with this combination.

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:1.4.1.RELEASE"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.M9"
    }
}
```

Here are few other useful links you might need to dig further.

http://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-4/common/client-dependencies.html
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Finchley-Release-Notes
https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/23/spring-cloud-finchley-m9-has-been-released

Comment: If this doesn't solve you problem, Post you build.gradle to invest further.